# script command execution hung forever in go program

Tags: bash, go

```
func Run() error {
    log.Info("In Run Command")
    cmd := exec.Command("bash", "/opt/AlterKafkaTopic.sh")
    stdout, err := cmd.StdoutPipe()
    if err != nil {
            return err
    }
    if err = cmd.Start(); err != nil {
           return err
    }
    f, err := os.Create(filepath.Join("/opt/log/", "execution.log"))
    if err != nil {
            return err
    }
    if _, err := io.Copy(f, stdout); err != nil {
            return err
    }
         if err := cmd.Wait(); err != nil {
            return err
    }
     return f.Close()
```

}

I am trying to execute a bash script from go code. The script changes some kafka topic properties. But the execution get hung `io.Copy(f, stdout)` and does not continue after it. 
This program is running on RHEL7.2 server.

Could someone suggest where I am going wrong

Comment: The bash script exit?

Try simple script with `echo something` for example.

Also check https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#CommandContext

Comment: Btw, you leave `f` not closed if `io.Copy` or `cmd.Wait` return an error. That's why `defer f.Close()` would be preferred.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [docs](https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#Cmd.StdoutPipe):

> Wait will close the pipe after seeing the command exit.

In other words, io.Copy exits when Wait() is called, but Wait is never called because it's blocked by Copy. Either run Copy in a goroutine, or simply assign `f` to `cmd.Stdout`:

```
f, err := os.Create(filepath.Join("/opt/log/", "execution.log"))
// TODO: Handle error
defer f.Close()

cmd := exec.Command("bash", "/opt/AlterKafkaTopic.sh")
cmd.Stdout = f
err = cmd.Run()
```